# Can Apple Mail and Calendar search directory contacts?

Tags: mail.app, calendar, contacts

I thought I'd try out Apple Calendar, here is my first stumbling block

We use Google Workspace, so I can normally make events with anyone in the company, google automatically searches for contacts from the directory, they are not all copied into my personal contact list

But apple apps seem not to use the directory search - the contacts app shows the directory is there, and i can search in the contacts app, but not when making an event or writing an email

Is there a fix for this?

I realise i could copy the whole company directory to my contacts, but thats annoying and wont add/remove people automatically.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if the contacts you want to invite to a certain event are in your contacts App, then the calendar app will be able to search through those. If they are not in there then.... well how would the calendar app know that contact? I am not quite sure what you mean by "the directory"